# How to move menu items from right to left using calabash-android

Tags: android, calabash

There are more than 10 menus in my application. If I open this application in android mobile, only 5 menus appear; I than have to swipe from right to left for the remaining menus to appear. Here I have used swipe keyword. But it hasn't worked.  Please see my below code:

```
  Scenario Outline: Go to file manager home page
    Then I wait for progress
    Then I swipe right
    Then I select the "Create" tab
```

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, you have some menu items that are not visible on the action bar and you want to click those menu items?